# What test to choose for comparing two population proportions and how to present it

Tags: proportion

I have a study where mothers and fathers of patients completed a questionnaire.
I want to compare the proportion of both samples that chose a response n:
348/913 mothers chose n
171/378 fathers chose n

With an online z-calculator i got a Z value of 2.37 which is significant at p=0.0178
My question is, is this test appropriate? Would you not use a t-test instead? Why/Whynot?

And how would i report my result?
"There was a significant difference between mothers' and fathers' choice of the response "n" (z = 2.37, p = .0178) with 45% of fathers choosing n while 38% of mother chose "n"".
Is this fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches are possible. I think the most direct is a
[test of binomial proportions](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm).
There are several slight variations of this test, including differences of opinion
whether make a continuity correction. Here is output from the procedure `prop.test` in R which implements one frequently used version. Depending on the exact formula you use and whether you make a continuity correction, you might get slightly different
results. But there is strong evidence (P-value about 0.02) that the proportions choosing `n` are different for mothers and fathers.

```
prop.test(c(348,171), c(913, 378))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    with continuity correction

data:  c(348, 171) out of c(913, 378)
X-squared = 5.348, df = 1, p-value = 0.02075
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.13233610 -0.01010379
sample estimates:
  prop 1   prop 2 
0.381161 0.452381
```

You could also make a 'contingency table' as shown below
and do a chi-squared test for homogeneity of probabilities
for mothers and fathers, which gives a significant result
(also with P-value 0.02).

```
Choice     Mothers   Fathers     TOTAL
--------------------------------------
  Yes        348       171         549
  No         565       207         772
--------------------------------------
TOTAL        913       378        1291
```

One advantage to using the table method is that it provides
an opportunity for an important 'reality check': the grand
total must be the total number of subjects in the study.

```
TBL = rbind(c(348,171), c(565,207))
chisq.test(TBL)

TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  348  171
[2,]  565  207

      Pearson's Chi-squared test 
      with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 5.348, df = 1, p-value = 0.02075
```

For counts as large as yours, some people feel that the Yates
correction should not be used. If it is not used, the P-value
is still very nearly 0.02.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.01755152
```

*Notes:* (1) Please look at the link to the NIST handbook or 
at a basic statistics text for one
of the two types of tests I illustrated above. And make
sure you understand the hypotheses being tested and how
to compute the test statistic.

(2) It is important for subjects in such a study to be selected
at random from an appropriate population. I would want to know
how random selection of subjects led to so many more mothers (913)
than fathers (378). I'm not saying there isn't a valid explanation,
but I would want to know it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as always very informative and impressive. Thing is, a lot of the time your answers are so advanced they go over my head haha with all this R stuff. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: Don't know how to respond to general complaint 'lot of the time...over my head...R stuff'. How about picking _one_ crucial spot where you don't understand, speculating about what my answer may mean, and asking a specific question? At least that opens up the possibility to learn something.

Comment: NOoooo I wasn't complaining sorry if it came across the wrong way. It's mainly because I have no prior experience with stats so a lot of things I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: OK, but still, the productive way forward is to pick one puzzling issue at a time, resolve that, and go on to the next puzzling issue. What is your first concrete, I hope answerable, question? // Over the long run, I think you will benefit if you get familiar with R. Valuable tool for computation, visualization, simulation. Free and lots of competently written help pgs Online. (Some not so helpfully written, but learn to ignore them.)

Comment: Definitely. From the limited exposure to the stats world seems like R is unavoidable. I understand your point and I think considering one puzzling issue at a time will also make for a better learning experience. Many thanks.